How to get am pm as capitalised in the following code without using any string method?
let d = new Date();    
let opts = {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  hour12: true,
};
console.log(1, Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', opts).format(d));
console.log(2, Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', opts).format(d));

output: 1 09:15:37 am, 2 09:15:37 AM
I need to use Indian locale but am pm as capital. Is there any property to opts to set to get the desired result?
I checked that US lacale default to AM PM. Can we change to am pm?

Doesn't look like you can, why do you need to use the Indian locale?
MDN Docs

Can't you just find and replace the am/pm in the formatted string?

Why without just capitalising if you don‘t mind asking?

Why without string method?

You could check the a/p character and change to AM/PM part, this will give probably the fastest solution with Intl.DateTimeFormat, which is critical with formatting many dates:


let opts = {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  hour12: true,
};
let s = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', opts).format(new Date);
s = s.slice(0, -2) + (s[s.length - 2] === 'a' ? 'AM' : 'PM');

console.log(s);



Anyway manually formatting a date is faster.

.slice is a string method. But honestly the constraint "no string methods" sounds strange and not useful anyway!

@CherryDT exactly, btw you can iterate the original string and concatenate chars into a new string which will be the same as slice ‍♂️

From everything I have looked into with Intl.DateTimeFormat there are only two available options for the hour12 option: true | false. So I am pretty sure there is no baked in way to format the string into uppercase without managing the string itself. It is interesting that it formats by default in US though.
There is a formatToParts() method that allows locale-aware formatting of strings produced by this Intl.DateTimeFormat object. Though I am not sure if this is what you want as you said without using string method...
Using the formatToParts() method along with .toUpperCase() in conditional and .join()


const d = new Date();

let opts = {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  hour12: true,
};

const meridianToUpper = (obj) => {
  // Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor
  const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', opts);
  
  // get the key/value parts
  const parts = dateTimeFormat.formatToParts(obj);
  // array to store parts
  const output = [];
  // map parts and check for the meridian or "dayPeriod"
  const partValues = parts.map((p) => {
    p.type === 'dayPeriod' ? output.push(p.value.toUpperCase()) : output.push(p.value);
  });
  // return the joined array as a string
  return output.join('');
}

// pass in your date obj into the function 
console.log(meridianToUpper(d));



Using the formatToParts() method with .toUpperCase() as described in MDN with a switch stmt and .join()


const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-IN", {
 hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  hour12: true,
})

//helper 
const dateString = formatter
  .formatToParts(new Date())
  .map(({ type, value }) => {
    // using a switch
    switch (type) {
      case "dayPeriod":
        return value.toUpperCase();
      default:
        return value;
    }
  })
  .join("");

console.log(dateString)



